# Links don't work on subpages

Tags: html, css

I'm sitting here scratching my head. There's a problem which in itself is stupid, but I'm unable to fix it! (Yeah you can say I'm stupider than the problem).
Anyway, I have website in which the header menu works on all the pages except on shows pages (there is a group of (Approx 10 pages) which lists different show details).
I have gone through each and every line to detect the problem, but no luck! Even the error console doesn't help me in any way.
Guidance would be appreciated.

Link where the header works :- www.amiteshgrover.com/shows.php

Link where the header doesn't work :- Just go to the shows page (the link mentioned above) and click on any show. Then try to hover on the menu bar, nothing happens? Exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#maincanvas` is covering the entire header menu.

Change the CSS to:

```
#mainCanvas {
  margin-top:60px;
  padding-top:20px;
  clear:both;
  position:static;
  min-width:940px;
  z-index:100;
  margin-left:125px;
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer, if you had noticed how the cursor didn't change to `pointer` you could have found it easily with `inspect element`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `#main-canvas` is in front of your menu, so when you try to click the menu, you're actually clicking `#main-canvas`.

`#main-canvas` has `z-index: 100` and `.nav` has no `z-index`.

To fix it, add `position: relative; z-index: 101;` to `.nav` or change your `padding-top` from `#main-canvas` to `margin-top`, this way the `#main-canvas` won't be at the same position as your menu are.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `sub_styles.css` is loaded on all other pages but this one, this style file is what gives the menu it's looks and since it's not loaded on those pages, you see the problematic menu.